# How to see n rows after a specific row

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to track user actions but I'd like to see what they do AFTER a specific event. How do I get the next n amount of lines?

For example below, I'd like to know what the user is doing after they "Get mushroom" to see if they are eating it. I'd want to reference the "Get mushroom" for each User and see the next few lines after that.

```
 User    Action
 Bob     Enter chapter 1
 Bob     Attack
 Bob     Jump
 Bob     Get mushroom
 Bob     Open inventory
 Bob     Eat mushroom 
 Bob     Close inventory
 Bob     Run
 Mary    Enter chapter 1
 Mary    Get mushroom
 Mary    Attack
 Mary    Jump
 Mary    Attack 
 Mary    Open inventory
 Mary    Close inventory
```

I'm not sure how to approach this after grouping by users. Expected results would be something like the below if i wanted 3 lines below

```
 User    Action
 Bob     Get mushroom # Action I want to find and the next 3 lines below it
 Bob     Open inventory
 Bob     Eat mushroom 
 Bob     Close inventory
 Mary    Get mushroom # Action I want to find and the next 3 lines below it
 Mary    Attack
 Mary    Jump
 Mary    Attack
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternatives with `dplyr` and `data.table`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(User) %>% 
  slice(rep(which(Action == 'Get-mushroom'), each=4) + 0:3)

library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, rep(.I[Action == 'Get-mushroom'], each=4) + 0:3, User]$V1]
```

both result in:

```
   User          Action
1:  Bob    Get-mushroom
2:  Bob  Open-inventory
3:  Bob    Eat-mushroom
4:  Bob Close-inventory
5: Mary    Get-mushroom
6: Mary          Attack
7: Mary            Jump
8: Mary          Attack
```

Answer (score 0):

First find out the indices which has the term `Get mushroom` using `which`

You can use `lapply` on every indices and get the next 3 indices using `seq`.

```
args <- which(df$Action == "Get mushroom")
df[unlist(lapply(args, function(x) seq(x, x+3))), ]

#   User         Action
#4   Bob    Get mushroom
#5   Bob  Open inventory
#6   Bob    Eat mushroom
#7   Bob Close inventory
#10 Mary    Get mushroom
#11 Mary         Attack
#12 Mary           Jump
#13 Mary         Attack
```

Or a similar approach (as suggested by @Sotos in comments)

```
df[sapply(args, function(x) seq(x, x+3)), ]
```

This `sapply` solution would work on dataframe and not on `data.table` as it does not accept 2-column matrix.

For it to work on `data.table`, you can unlist it using `c`

```
df[c(sapply(args, function(x) seq(x, x+3))), ]
```

Comment: You can avoid unlisting `lapply` by using `sapply(args, ...)`

Comment: @Sotos yes, definitely! Updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @RonakShah your first method of unlist(lapply(args...)) works but not the sapply version. Any idea what's going on? // Error in `[.data.table`(mushroom, sapply(args, function(x) seq(x, x +  : 
  i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please let datatable-help know if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #657.

Comment: @ant `sapply` solution works on dataframe. Your input looks like a `data.table`. The output of `saaply` is a 2-column matrix which dataframe accepts but that doesn't seem to be the case with `data.table`. We need to convert that into 1 dimensional array using `c`. See updated post.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you so much! I appreciate the help, I was stuck on this problem for a while since I'm new to data.table!

Comment: @ant Glad, it could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     df
   User         Action
1   Bob  Enterchapter1
2   Bob         Attack
3   Bob           Jump
4   Bob    Getmushroom
5   Bob  Openinventory
6   Bob    Eatmushroom
7   Bob Closeinventory
8   Bob            Run
9  Mary  Enterchapter1
10 Mary    Getmushroom
11 Mary         Attack
12 Mary           Jump
13 Mary         Attack
14 Mary  Openinventory
15 Mary Closeinventory

indices <- which(df$Action == 'Getmushroom')
n <- 3  
# ensure that x + n does not go beyond the #rows of df
do.call(rbind, lapply(indices, function(x)df[x:min(x+n, nrow(df)),]))


User         Action
4   Bob    Getmushroom
5   Bob  Openinventory
6   Bob    Eatmushroom
7   Bob Closeinventory
10 Mary    Getmushroom
11 Mary         Attack
12 Mary           Jump
13 Mary         Attack
```